# How to get a building block image in VSTO Add-In?

Tags: ms-word, vsto, office-interop

I use a RibbomGallery to select a building block and would show (thumbnail) image.

```
RibbonDropDownItem item = Factory.CreateRibbonDropDownItem();
item.Label = buildingBlock.Name;
item.Tag = buildingBlock.ID;
// item.OfficeImageId = "CustomCoverPageGallery"; 
item.Image = ?
gallery.Items.Add(item);
```

How can i get a image of a building block (for example cover page) ?

VS 2017 VSTO Add-In Word 2016.

Comment: Take a screen shot...

Comment: An image screen shot as a file must be created, updated, deployed, binded ... an image must be syncronized. It's just a workaround. 
But how does Word make a building block image at runtime? For example in WdWordDialog.wdDialogBuildingBlockOrganizer or in insert cover page dialog. 
I need an actual image of building block at runtime.

Comment: Microsoft has never revealed how Word does it - this capability is not made available to developers. I would guess there's some kind of tool that can render the Word Open XML (similar to how the Word, application, itself does so). Perhaps you can find such a tool, somewhere. Or maybe convert the Word Open XML to PDF if there's a tool "out there" that can render and return a graphic from PDF file format.